# How to spot missing value from two GROUP_CONCAT columns?

Tags: mysql

I have table `All Badges` and table `User Badge`.

The value in `User Badge` can all be found on the `All Badges` and each user_id can have multiple `User Badge` so I use GROUP_CONCAT to group the value based on the user_id. The goal of the `User Badge` is to allow users to collect all available badges, thus they will need information about the missing badge on their profile.

Here is the `All Badges` table:

```
|---------------|-----------|
|   Badge_ID    |   Label   |
|---------------|-----------|
|       1       |     a     |
|       2       |     b     |
|       3       |     c     |
|       4       |     d     |
|       5       |     e     |
|---------------|-----------|
```

The `User Badge` table:

```
|------------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|  User_Badge_ID   |  Badge_Label  |    user_ID    |  fk_badge_id  |
|------------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|        1         |       a       |       1       |       1       |
|        2         |       a       |       2       |       1       |
|        3         |       b       |       1       |       2       |
|        4         |       a       |       3       |       1       |
|        5         |       b       |       2       |       2       |
|        6         |       c       |       2       |       3       |
|        7         |       d       |       2       |       4       |
|------------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
```

I have this query to group the badge on user_id, but I don't know the query to show the missing value.

```
SELECT
     user_badge.user_id AS User_ID
     GROUP_CONCAT(user_badge.Badge_Label) AS User_Badge
FROM
     User_Badge
```

The desired result. The missing badge will be added into the new column called `Missing Badge`.

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      User_ID        |    User_Badge    |   Missing Badge  |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |       a, b       |     c, d, e      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |     a, b, c, d   |         e        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         a        |    b, c, d, e    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Any ideas to show the missing value from each user_id? Many thanks for your willingness to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select s.user_id,
         group_concat(case when fk_badge_id is not null then s.label end) 'user_badge',
         group_concat(case when fk_badge_id is null then s.label end) 'missing'
from
(
SELECT distinct USER_ID,badge_id,ab.label
FROM USER_BADGE ub
CROSS JOIN ALL_BADGES ab
) s
left join user_badge ub on ub.user_id = s.user_id and ub.fk_badge_id = s.badge_id
group by s.user_id;
```

Where the sub query s gets all the badges a user could have using a cross join and the main query checks those he/she has or not , the left join returning nulls if has not.

```
+---------+------------+---------+
| user_id | user_badge | missing |
+---------+------------+---------+
|       1 | a,b        | c,d,e   |
|       2 | a,b,c,d    | e       |
|       3 | a          | c,d,e,b |
+---------+------------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it helps me a lot to breakdown the problem.